# Dojo javascript toolkit, i have two defined functions inside one module. How can i call one from another

Tags: javascript, scope, dojo

```
define([" ... "], function (...) {
    return {        
        f1: function () { f2(); },
        f2: function() { ... }        
    }
}
```

I want to call `f2` function inde the `f1` function but getting error:

> f2 is not a function.

How can I call it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Call it using this (scope of defined module ) , should be like

```
define([" ... "], function (...) {
    return {        
        f1: function () { this.f2(); }, // <-------------
        f2: function() { ... }        
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this works. thank you.



define([], function () {
 return {
  f1: function () { this.f2(); }, // <-------------
  f2: function () { alert("here"); }
 }
});

Comment: @gizgi great :)